# Show that $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be of  class $C^k$ with $k\geq1$, such that $|g'(x)|< 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ define by $f(x)=x+g(x)$ is a  diffeomorphism od class $C^k$ in some open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Show with an example that the condition $|g'(x)|\leq \alpha<1$, could not be replace for showing that $f$ is surjective.

I know by the Inverse function theorem that:

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ open, $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ of class $C^k$, $k\geq1$. Supposed that for some $x_0 \in U$, $Df(x_0):\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a isomorphism, then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism of class $C^k$ from some neighborhood $V_{x_0}\subseteq U$ to some neighborhood $W_{f(x_0)}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.

I do not know how to use the fact $|g'(x)|< 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, to prove that $Df(x_0):\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a isomorphism.

I did this:

As $g$ is continuous $$||g(x)-g(y)||\leq ||x-y||Sup\{||Dg((1-t)x+ty)||:0\leq t \leq 1\}$$

But I don't feel it will be the way, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x_0$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m\backslash\{0\}$, $$| Df(x_0)(v)|=| v- Dg(x_0)(v)| \ge |v|-|Dg(x_0)(v)| \stackrel{|g'|<1}{>} |v|-|v|=0$$
Thus $|Df(x_0)(v)| $ is non null for all $v$ non null, or $Df(x_0)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: As $Dg(x_0)$ is linear then $Dg(x_0)$ is inyective, but how do we ensure that it is surjective?

Comment: An injective linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to itself so...

Comment: Offcorse, thanks for yout time!